# NetSuite SuiteScript How to bridge the 10MG limit?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

HI and thanks for any help. Is there a way to work with files larger than 10mg? I have to check for updates on items in a file that would be uploaded, but the file contains all items in the system and is approximately 20MG. This 10MG limit is killing me. I see streaming for file save and appending but not for file reading. So I am open to any suggestions. The provider in this instance doesn't offer the facility to chunk the files. thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using SS2 to process a file from the file cabinet then if you use file.lines.iterator() to process a file the size limit is 10MB *per line*.

I believe returning a file object from a map reduce script's getInputStage automatically parses the file into lines.

The 10MB file size limit comes into play if you try to create a file larger than 10MB.

If you are trying to read in a an external file via script then one approach that I've used is to proxy the call via an external service. e.g. query an AWS lambda function that checks for and saves the file to S3. Return the file path and size to your SuiteScript. The SuiteScript then asks for "pages" of the file that are less than 10MB and saves those. If you are uploading something like a .csv then the lambda function can send the header with each paged request.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I was not aware of this at all, I will check it out and let you know how it went, thanks for your help, awesome, a life saver.

Comment: Ok, it works great thanks again, this really blows out the file limitation and makes less annoyed at NS this week. :)